# Efficient computation and redoing graphics actions

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Are there any general guidelines on how Matlab handles graphics-based commands that ultimately result in no action being taken?  A simple illustrative example--note the actual computational cost here is quite negligible:

```
fig=figure;
ax=axes;
for i=1:10
    data=myFunction(i)       %e.g. rand(i)
    plot(data)
    hold(ax,'on')            %perform this repeatedly even though it's only needed once
end
```

versus:

```
fig=figure;
ax=axes;
for i=1:10
    data=myFunction(i)       %e.g. rand(i)
    plot(data)
    if ~ishold(ax)
        hold(ax,'on')        %perform this only if it is needed
    end
end
```

If Matlab internally determines whether the `hold(ax,'on')` command is needed before actually doing it, then presumably the computational cost is similar or lower for the first form.  The coding is also simpler to implement and read.  But, if the action is carried out in full, then there are cases where it would be better, from a computational cost standpoint, to use the second form.

It's worth noting that the definition of "no action" here is deliberately vague, there's a lot of nuance here.  For instance, it's easy to create an example where Matlab must perform *some level* of computation before it can evaluate whether the graphics command would have no effect.  For instance, in `colormap(myColormapFunction)`, Matlab would have to call `myColormapFunction` in order to evaluate whether what it returns is the same as the existing plot's `CData` property.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no official guidelines on how "no action" commands are handled by the built-in MATLAB functions. Meanwhile, MathWorks does provide guidelines for optimizing graphics performance; which I feel, is a much more important thing to consider.

- [Graphics Performance Documentation Page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-performance.html)

Now I apologize in advance if the following section doesn't answer your question. But if you are truly curious about the behind the scenes and real-world performance, you should use the provided [Code Profiling Tool](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html), and [built-in timing functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html).

With that said, the next section is about optimizing graphics performance in general.

---

For example, in the code you've provided, I would strongly recommend against putting `hold` and `plot` in the for-loop to begin with. From my experience, these are never necessary and can be optimized away.

Here, I'm guessing that you are trying to animate MATLAB plots; in which case, try updating the plot markers instead of using the plot function. For example:

```
figure
% Plot an empty plot with placeholder values (NaNs) the size of your data
% Save handle to plot object as `h`
h = plot( nan(size(data)) ); 

for i = 1:10
    [Xdata, Ydata] = MyFunction(...);
    
    % Update your plot markers with the handle update method
    h.XData = Xdata;
    h.YData = Ydata;

    drawnow % drawnow to see animation
end
```

In this case, I don't even need to use the `hold` function, since I'm just updating the same plot, which is *much faster*.

---

Even if your function is outputting new data series, and you want to plot them on top of the old data series, you can use the same trick; *it will only require you to pre-allocate the plot handles and data arrays.* (Which, honestly is a good programming practice in general.)

```
figure
hold on % Hold the plot now

N = 100; % Number of data series you expect to have
H = cell(N,1); % Preallocate N Cells for all the plot handles
for i = 1:N
    % Save plot handles to cell array in a loop, if you have so many series
    H{i} = plot ( nan(size(data)) );
end


% Your iterative function calls
for t = 1:100
    ...
    % Iteratively update all plot handles with a syntax like this
    % (Not entirely sure, this is off the top of my head)
    for i = 1:N
        H{i}.XData = newX;
        H{i}.YData = newY;
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm familiar with most of this, though I don't have a sense for just how important it is for the preallocated data size to match the actual plot data size, which might not always be possible.

Comment: @TTT In my experience, that depends on the number of objects being drawn. It can be noticeably faster for large numbers of objects, to update just the markers that have changed, rather than the entire marker "array" -- which is only possible if you preallocate. However, I don't have anything to back that up but anecdotal evidence, so do take it with a grain of salt.